# UWP VideoProperties empty on StorageFile immediately after MediaCapture.StopRecordAsync()?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, ms-media-foundation

When retrieving the VideoProperties of a freshly created MediaCapture file, I am finding that frequently the properties are not set, i.e. all zero. To illustrate I've updated the CameraStarterKit sample in the Windows universal samples zip:

```
    private async Task StopRecordingAsync()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Stopping recording...");

        _isRecording = false;

        await _mediaCapture.StopRecordAsync();

        var videoproperties = await videoFile.Properties.GetVideoPropertiesAsync();

        // This Assert will fail most of the time but not always
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(videoproperties.Duration != TimeSpan.Zero);

        Debug.WriteLine("Stopped recording!");
    }
```

I'm not receiving any errors, just bad data. Viewing the file properties in File Explorer always shows the expected result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any chance the file is not yet finalized by the code that produced it?

Comment: How often does this happen? If you add a delay (e.g. `await Task.Delay(1000);`) between `StopRecordAsync()` and `GetVideoPropertiesAsync()`, does it become any more reliable?